# Change 'ok' button on alert box to stop moving further

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, alert

I have a form with 3 fields and I want to check (using javascript) whether all of them are filled with some data.

```
= f.button :submit, "Create", onclick: "myFunction()", class: "btn btn-success"   

      function myFunction() {
        var a = $('select#a').find(":selected").val();
        var b = $('select#b').find(":selected").val();
        var c = $('select#c').find(":selected").val();
        if (a == "" || b == "" || c == "") {
          alert("All fields have to be filled");
        };
      }
```

I want an 'ok' button on alert box make a user stay on the form to continue providing the data (right now it shows an alert box but still moves further to the controller action).

Comment: `alert('...'); return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your onclick:

```
onclick: "return myFunction()"
```

And your function:

```
function myFunction() {
    var a = $('select#a').find(":selected").val();
    var b = $('select#b').find(":selected").val();
    var c = $('select#c').find(":selected").val();
    if (a == "" || b == "" || c == "") {
      alert("All fields have to be filled");
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
       return true;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use "return false" in this block.

```
if (a == "" || b == "" || c == "") {
      alert("All fields have to be filled");
      return false; // use this
}
```